# How do I correct a URL Inspection API error?

Tags: url, search, console

I am trying to have the URL inspection API for my site, but I keep getting this error:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "You do not own this site, or the inspected URL is not part of this property.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Trying to find out how to get this corrected.

Answer (score 3):

First of all your email should have permission for accessing the `siteUrl` value that you have given in the inspection API. You can check your permission in the [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console/) by login with your email. Secondly, In the `siteUrl` you need to give the exact website URL that you are registered in the Google Search Console. In my case, I got the same error because I have given

```json
{
  "inspectionUrl": "https://test.com/my-test-inspection-url",
  "siteUrl": "https://test.com",
  "languageCode": "en-US"
}
```

Instead of

```json
{
      "inspectionUrl": "https://test.com/my-test-inspection-url",
      "siteUrl": "https://test.com/",
      "languageCode": "en-US"
    }
```

I have registered my website name as `https://test.com/` in Google Search Console and I have given the `siteUrl` value as `https://test.com`

Comment: Great answer, thanks